# How to create AAR library from react native project

Tags: android, react-native, aar

I need to integrate two projects into a single Android application.
Project-1 is a native Android application and Project-2 is react-native application.

I have a few questions:

1. Can Integrate native android and react-native project into a single native android application?
2. Can I import the react-native project into the native Android application as AAR file or another format so I can directly access or call activity which is present in react native code?